# Binding Listview SelectedItems for Actions

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I'm struggling to bind 2 listviews selected items to my viewmodel.
The idea is to have a view with 2 listviews and 2 buttons in between to move the
 (multiple) selected items from 1 listview to another (2 way).

The view:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="DuamResources" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding SelectedDuamResources}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="&lt;" Width="40" Margin="5" cal:Message.Attach="AddSelectedResources($datacontext)"/>
        <Button Content="&gt;" Width="40" Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="AvailableDuamResources" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Type}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The associated viewmodel properties:

```
private ObservableCollection<DuamResourceInfo> availableDuamResources;
        public ObservableCollection<DuamResourceInfo> AvailableDuamResources
        {
            get { return availableDuamResources; }
            set { availableDuamResources = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AvailableDuamResources); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DuamResourceInfo> selectedDuamResources;
        public ObservableCollection<DuamResourceInfo> SelectedDuamResources
        {
            get { return selectedDuamResources; }
            set { selectedDuamResources = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedDuamResources); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DuamResourceInfo> duamResources;
        public ObservableCollection<DuamResourceInfo> DuamResources
        {
            get { return duamResources; }
            set { duamResources = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DuamResources); }
        }
```

The code I want to achieve:

```
public void AddSelectedResources(IEnumerable<DuamResourceInfo> resources)
{

}

public void RemoveSelectedResources(IEnumerable<DuamResourceInfo> resources)
{

}
```

I'm using **Caliburn Micro** for MVVM. I know there are some conventions for binding but I'm not sure they apply to this scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "x:Bind" instead of "Binding"? For some reason in the past one or the other has worked for me, but not both, depending on the situation.